# Finding <div> in html using C#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, pack

I've seen some results on StackOverflow already on a similar topic and they all recommended the HTML Agility Pack. I've also found a few examples on it too, but it isn't working. My current code:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        List<string> facts = new List<string>();
        foreach (HtmlNode li in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"))
        {
            facts.Add(li.InnerText);
            foreach (String s in facts)
            {
                textBox1.Text += s + "/n";
            }
        }
```

I get the error *Null reference was unhandled* on *doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")*.

Also, as another question, how do I find a specific div with a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as to q1: it looks right to me. Are you certain the document is loaded properly..

r.e. q2: use xpath: `div[@id='idToFind']`

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. LoadHTML doesn't support URI's it seems, so I have to load an actual webpage from my computer I believe.

Comment: yeah, your right. its been a while since i used hap. It is the bomb. glad i could help.